# Redirect from SoftwareRecommendations.stackexchange.com to SoftwareRecs.stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, advertising, redirection

We are trying to advertise Software Recommendations in various venues.

It is not easy to advertise `SoftwareRecs.stackexchange.com` because `Recs` is not explicit.

`SoftwareRecommendations.stackexchange.com` would be easier to market.
The URL is more understandable.

If it is easy and not a burden to maintain, could we have a redirect from [SoftwareRecommendations.stackexchange.com](http://SoftwareRecommendations.stackexchange.com) to [SoftwareRecs.stackexchange.com](http://SoftwareRecs.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: supercalifragilisticexpialidocious.stackexchange.com :D)

Comment: Or maybe sr.se.com?

Comment: @hjpotter92: I actually tried but `se.com` seems to not belong to StackExchange.